# is there a way to get the number of children of a node without loading all the node data in Android?

Tags: android, firebase

My datastructure (userdetails)

```
-KCV32vWQECRlMvlgkGO
    Name: "asdf"
    Phoneid: "1zlkflakfhkf0e8"
    Phoneno: "9478567899"
-KCV3s-lwv5i-VvFBaxq
    Name: "asas"
    Phoneid: "1c584jbascjasc8"
    Phoneno: "9999999999"
```

My method

```
queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Size "+arg0.getChildrenCount());
    }
```

How to get a count of 2? I am getting 3 two times because each time it goes inside and get child separately.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the snapshot that a `child_added` event gives you is the new child data. So `getChildrenCount()` counts how many *properties* (children) the new child has (and it has 3).

To do what you want you should add a `ValueEventListener` event like so:

```
queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
    }

    public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot arg0, String arg1) {
        System.out.println("Size "+arg0.getChildrenCount());
    }
});
```

This should return all the children at `queryRef` location every time the value changes (e.g new child).

Tell me if this works as I can't try it myself.